# Facebook share callback, more data?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using a simple Facebook share dialog:

```java
FB.ui(
        {
          method: 'share',
          href: 'http://example.com'
        },
        function(response) {
          if (response && response.post_id) {
            alert('Post was published.'+JSON.stringify(response));
          } else {
            alert('Post was not published.'+linkToShare);
          }
        }
      );
```

When I get a success callback, all it gives me is the `post id`. Is there a way to get more data?

What I really want to know is how the page was shared e.g. Only Me, Friends or Public

Is this data out there anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know more, you need to use [OAuth](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens?locale=de_DE) to get information about the web app using user.
Example:

> FB.api('/me', function(response) {
>         console.log(response);
>       });

**EDIT**: [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post?locale=de_DE) you can find out more about to get information from a single post